# C# create 24/32bit sound wav file

Tags: c#, wav, 32-bit

I'm following this tutorial on Microsoft Developer blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dawate/2009/06/24/intro-to-audio-programming-part-3-synthesizing-simple-wave-audio-using-c/

The tutorial is called "Intro to Audio Programming" and I followed all steps, but probably I missed something.

This is a configuration piece extracted from `WaveFormatChunk` class in his homonym method:

```
    sChunkID = "fmt ";
    dwChunkSize = 16;
    wFormatTag = 1;
    wChannels = 2;
    dwSamplesPerSec = 44100;
    wBitsPerSample = 16;
    wBlockAlign = (ushort)(wChannels * (wBitsPerSample / 8));
    dwAvgBytesPerSec = dwSamplesPerSec * wBlockAlign;
```

The `wBitsPerSample` set the bit depth of the generated function, pretty simple till now.

Then, running the program, all is working with this settings. Generating 1Hz frequency with amplitude 32760 at 16bit / 44.1ksample this is the result:

[1Hz 16bit 44.1k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS30h.png)

And that is obviously a correct output.

Now I quote it:

> we use an array of shorts because we have 16-bit samples as specified in the format block. If you want to change to 8-bit audio, use an array of bytes. If you want to use 32-bit audio, use an array of floats.

Talking about `shortArray` in `WaveDataChunk` class

```
public class WaveDataChunk
{
    public string sChunkID;     // "data"
    public uint dwChunkSize;    // Length of header in bytes
    public short[] shortArray;
```

Then, for 32bit audio, changing the `shortArray` to float:

```
public float[] shortArray;
```

and `wBitsPerSample` to 32:

```
wBitsPerSample = 32;
```

This is the result:
[1Hz 32bit 44.1k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgu1C.png)

Practically, the frequency is doubled and only half of the time is written. What did I do wrong?? What I've to do?

Comment: Don't know what you did wrong. Start by analyzing the WAV file you produces. Is it really a 32 bit WAV file? Is it really 44.1 kHz? Are the screenshots from Audacity? If not, what tool did you use to visualize the waveform? Also, if you use float samples, the format should perhaps be WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT (i am not entirely sure about this, though)

Comment: @elgonzo analyzing the file actually is a 32bit WAV with 44.1kHz... but i don't know why the output is this. Yes, is audacity

Comment: Can you upload the WAV file somewhere?

Comment: Before you try uploading somewhere, what is the precise file size of the WAV file? It should have a size (assuming a time span of 1 sec)  of about 44100*4*2+header bytes (~350 KB)

Comment: @elgonzo Not 350kb, the half. I see in this link: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html that 32bit are not PCM files, then i changed FormatTag from 1 to 3 (float), a strange wave come out. Then changed also the chunk size from 16 to 18 or 40, but 18/40 the wav file is corrupted.

Comment: If you use float values for your wave form, you will have to use a normalized value range, which is the range from 1 (max. positive amplitude) to -1 (max. negative amplitude). But then again, it is not really related to your problem, so leave it as you originally had. Since your WAV file only is half the size of 350KB then it of course only has data for half the desired time span of 1 second. That is your problem. Figure out why your code only writes half of the samples required for 1 second and then fix it... ;-) (Do you by accident only generate data for one channel?)

Comment: "_Then changed also the chunk size from 16 to 18 or 40, but 18/40 the wav file is corrupted._" Before taking potshots at making arbitrary changes to WAV header files, it would be a good idea to consult some WAV format specification document to see what each of those fields you want to change really indicates and what the effect of those changed values would be...

Comment: Your generator loop is wrong (e.g. `numSamples` or so) with the 32-bit floats. However you have not posted that piece of the code, so everyone is just guessing. You need to specify the other format in the header and use an array of floats instead of shorts, then you need to cast the sine function to float instead of short (and the range should be -1..1 when using floating-point for audio AFAIK). The chunksize remains unchanged as the header format does not change, only the data does.

Comment: Here is the code of `numSamples = (format.dwSamplesPerSec * format.wChannels * (format.wBitsPerSample / 8));` @Lucero

Comment: @Lucero ok I think I've solved: `numSamples = (format.dwSamplesPerSec * format.wChannels * (format.wBitsPerSample / 16));` and changed also the angle of the wave: `t = (Math.PI * 2 * freq) / (format.dwSamplesPerSec * format.wChannels * (format.wBitsPerSample / 16));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use IEEE floating points, the range should be -1..1 (instead of the min..max integer number). Also, the format is then no longer MS PCM (1) but IEEE FLOAT (3).

The problem with the article is that its chunk definitions are initialized without IEEE FLOAT format in mind. Here's a suggestion of mine to make the code more generic (literally); the chunks will initialize the fields (which I made read-only) in the constructor depending on the type chosen:

```
public class WaveFormatChunk<T> where T: struct, IConvertible
{
    public readonly string sChunkID;         // Four bytes: "fmt "
    public readonly uint dwChunkSize;        // Length of chunk in bytes
    public readonly ushort wFormatTag;       // 1 (MS PCM)
    public readonly ushort wChannels;        // Number of channels
    public readonly uint dwSamplesPerSec;    // Frequency of the audio in Hz... 44100
    public readonly uint dwAvgBytesPerSec;   // for estimating RAM allocation
    public readonly ushort wBlockAlign;      // sample frame size, in bytes
    public readonly ushort wBitsPerSample;    // bits per sample

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a format chunk. Supported data types: byte, short, float
    /// </summary>
    public WaveFormatChunk(short channels, uint samplesPerSec)
    {
        sChunkID = "fmt ";
        dwChunkSize = 16;
        wFormatTag = typeof(T) == typeof(float) || typeof(T) == typeof(double) ? 3 : 1;
        wChannels = channels;
        dwSamplesPerSec = samplesPerSec;
        wBitsPerSample = (ushort)(Marshal.SizeOf<T>() * 8);
        wBlockAlign = (ushort)(wChannels * ((wBitsPerSample + 7) / 8));
        dwAvgBytesPerSec = dwSamplesPerSec * wBlockAlign;            
    }
}

public class WaveDataChunk<T> where T: struct, IConvertible
{
    public readonly string sChunkID;     // "data"
    public readonly uint dwChunkSize;    // Length of data chunk in bytes
    public readonly T[] dataArray;  // 8-bit audio

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new data chunk with a specified capacity.
    /// </summary>
    public WaveDataChunk(uint capacity)
    {
        dataArray = new T[capacity];
        dwChunkSize = (uint)(Marshal.SizeOf<T>() * capacity);
        sChunkID = "data";
    }   
}

public void FloatWaveGenerator(WaveExampleType type)
{          
    // Init chunks
    header = new WaveHeader();
    format = new WaveFormatChunk<float>(2, 44100);
    data = new WaveDataChunk<float>(format.dwSamplesPerSec * format.wChannels);            

    // Fill the data array with sample data
    switch (type)
    {
        case WaveExampleType.ExampleSineWave:
            double freq = 440.0f;   // Concert A: 440Hz

            // The "angle" used in the function, adjusted for the number of channels and sample rate.
            // This value is like the period of the wave.
            double t = (Math.PI * 2 * freq) / format.dwSamplesPerSec;

            for (uint i = 0; i < format.dwSamplesPerSec - 1; i++)
            {
                // Fill with a simple sine wave at max amplitude
                for (int channel = 0; channel < format.wChannels; channel++)
                {
                    data.dataArray[i * format.wChannels + channel] = (float)Math.Sin(t * i);
                }                        
            }

            break;
    }          
}
```

Note that you'll need to adjust the variables used by the FloatWaveGenerator, and the foreach loop saving the data must write the correct data type as well. I leave this as an exercise to you. :)

Comment: Thank for the contribute (can't vote +1 for my rep), that is using IEEE FLOAT, and that is working. But `numSamples = (format.dwSamplesPerSec * format.wChannels * (format.wBitsPerSample / 16));` and `t = (Math.PI * 2 * freq) / (format.dwSamplesPerSec * format.wChannels * (format.wBitsPerSample / 16));` works pretty well too, and the amplitude is still 32760. With those, without changing the format, I can generate 32bit with PCM. How about 24bit now? (with PCM encoding).

Comment: @J.Doe You can accept the answer even if you cannot vote. That being said, for 24bit use 32bit but store only the first three (most significant) bytes of each value. You can use the BitConverter class to convert the 32bits to an array of 4 bytes, and then write 3 bytes if this array for each sample.

Comment: @J.Doe `foreach (var dataPoint in data.dataArray) { var dataBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(dataPoint); writer.Write(dataBytes, 1, 3); }`